# send an arbitrary number of inputs from python to a .exe

Tags: python, executable

```
p = subprocess.Popen(args = "myprog.exe" + " " +
                     str(input1) + " " +
                     str(input2) + " " +
                     str(input3) + " " +
                     strpoints, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

in the code above, input1, input2, and input3 are all integers that get converted to strings. the variable "strpoints" is a list of arbitrary length of strings. input1 tells myprog the length of strpoints. of course, when i try to run the above code, i get the following error message:

> TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly

how do i pass all the elements of strpoints to myprog.exe? am i doomed to having to do str(strpoints) and then have myprog.exe parse this for commas, apostrophes, etc.? e.g.,

> `>>> x = ['a', 'b']
>
> `>>> str(x)
>
> "['a', 'b']"

or should i create a huge string in advance? e.g.,

> '>>> x = ['a', 'b']
>
> '>>> stringify(x)
>
> ' a b'

where stringify would be something like

```
def stringify(strlist):
    rlist = ""
    for i in strlist:
        rlist = rlist + i + " "
    return rlist
```

Comment: You might want to rethink how you pass data to the subprocess.  If you use this method, you are likely to run afoul of the maximum command line length.  On Windows XP or greater this happens to be 8191 characters.

Comment: oh? i'm in vista. does that change things? i don't know how else to send the data other than to save it to a file and have myprog read it from file.

Comment: nope.  As far as I know there aren't any operating systems at all that have unbounded command line length.  for instance linux has a much longer command length, at 32767 characters, but its still possible to exhaust even that.  If your inputs could be anything besides hand crafted to work for sure, then you should probably use a pipe or file, on any operating system.

Comment: well it finally happened. i got the file name too long error message. guess i should be smart and store all the data in a file and just have the .exe read from the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using string.join:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(args = "myprog.exe" + " " +
                     str(input1) + " " +
                     str(input2) + " " +
                     str(input3) + " " +
                     " ".join(strpoints), stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 7):

args can be a sequence:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(args = ["myprog.exe"] + 
                            [str(x) for x in [input1,input2,input3]] + 
                            strpoints,stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

This is more correct if your arguments contain shell metacharacters e.g. ' * and you don't want them interpreted as such.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid concatenating all arguments into one string using that string.

It's a lot simpler and better and safer to just pass a sequence (list or tuple) of arguments. This is specially true if any argument contains a space character (which is quite common for filenames).

Answer (score 0):

Any thought that you might want to enclose those strings in quotes, in case they have embedded spaces?  Something like:

```
if strpoints:
    finalargs = '"' + '" "'.join(strpoints) + '"'
else:
    finalargs = ""
p = subprocess.Popen(args = "myprog.exe" + " " +
                 str(input1) + " " +
                 str(input2) + " " +
                 str(input3) + " " +
                 finalargs, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

This makes your string longer, but will preserve the integrity of your individual elements in the list.